Send custom metrics to Opentelemetry from AWS Lambda using NodeJS
I have AWS Lambda which collects and calculates data (in histogram format).

I want to send that data to Prometheus using Opentelemetry.
I can't use PushGateWay for security reasons.
As I run lambda, I don't have API or expose API to scrape.

I've attached layer (arn:aws:lambda::184161586896:layer:opentelemetry-nodejs-0_9_0:4),
I've tried following code to send custom metrics and other solutions, but none of them worked.
import { MeterProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';
import { OTLPMetricExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-http';

OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_ENDPOINT = "<endpoint URL>";

const otlpMetricExporter = new OTLPMetricExporter({
    url: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_ENDPOINT 
});

const meterProvider = new MeterProvider({
    exporter: otlpMetricExporter
});

const meter = meterProvider.getMeter('meter-name');

const blockingTimeHistogram = meter.createHistogram('metric1', {
    description: 'metric1',
    boundaries: [0, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],  // Custom boundaries for milliseconds
});

export const recordMetrics = async (metric1) => {
    try {
        blockingTimeHistogram.record(parseFloat(metric1), { metricName: "name" });
       
        //  await meterProvider.forceFlush();
        meterProvider.shutdown();

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Prometheus call failed with Error : " + error);
    }
};


